# Processing html text nodes with scrapy and XPath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to process documents like this one:

```
...
<div class="contents">
    some text
    <ol>
        <li>
            more text
        </li>
        ...
    </ol>
</div>
...
```

I want to collect all the text inside the contents area into a string.
I also need the '1., 2., 3....' from the `<li>` elements, so my result should be `'some text 1. more text...'`

So, I'm looping over `<div class="contents">`'s children

```
for n in response.xpath('//div[@class="contents"]/node()'):
    if n.xpath('self::ol'):
        result += process_list(n)
    else:
        result += n.extract()
```

If `n`is an ordered list, I loop over its elements and add a number to `li/text()` (in `process_list()`). If `n`is a text node itself, I just read its value.
However, `'some text'` doesn't seem to be part of the node set, since the loop doesn't get inside the `else` part. My result is `'1. more text'`

Finding text nodes relative to their parent node works:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="contents"]//text()')
```

finds all the text, but this way I can't add the list item numbers.

What am I doing wrong and is there a better way to achieve my task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrapy's Selectors use `lxml` under the hood, but [`lxml` doesn't work with XPath calls on text nodes](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/996134).

```
>>> import scrapy
>>> s = scrapy.Selector(text='''<div class="contents">
...     some text
...     <ol>
...         <li>
...             more text
...         </li>
...         ...
...     </ol>
... </div>''')
>>> s.xpath('.//div[@class="contents"]/node()')
[<Selector xpath='.//div[@class="contents"]/node()' data='\n    some text\n    '>, <Selector xpath='.//div[@class="contents"]/node()' data='<ol>\n        <li>\n            more text\n'>, <Selector xpath='.//div[@class="contents"]/node()' data='\n'>]
>>> for n in s.xpath('.//div[@class="contents"]/node()'):
...     print(n.xpath('self::ol'))
... 
[]
[<Selector xpath='self::ol' data='<ol>\n        <li>\n            more text\n'>]
[]
```

But you could hack into the underlying lxml object to test it's type for a text node (it's "hidden" in a `.root` attribute of each scrapy Selector):

```
>>> for n in s.xpath('.//div[@class="contents"]/node()'):
...     print([type(n.root), n.root])
... 
[<class 'str'>, '\n    some text\n    ']
[<class 'lxml.etree._Element'>, <Element ol at 0x7fa020f2f9c8>]
[<class 'str'>, '\n']
```

An alternative is to use some HTML-to-text conversion library like [html2text](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html2text)

```
>>> import html2text
>>> html2text.html2text("""<div class="contents">
...     some text
...     <ol>
...         <li>
...             more text
...         </li>
...         ...
...     </ol>
... </div>""")
'some text\n\n  1. more text \n...\n\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

If `n` is not an `ol` element, `self::ol` yields an empty node set. What is `n.xpath(...)` supposed to return when the result of the expression is an empty node set?

An empty node set is "falsy" in XPath, but you're not evaluating it as a boolean in XPath, only in Python. Is an empty node set falsy in Python?

If that's the problem, you could fix it by changing the `if` statement to

```
if n.xpath('boolean(self::ol)'):
```

or

```
if n.xpath('count(self::ol) > 1'):
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it didn't work. If the node set is empty, `n.xpath(...)` returns an empty list, which should be falsy in Python. In the above example the `else` path should be entered in the first iteration, but it isn't. Explicitly testing for a text node with `if n.xpath('self::text()')` doesn't work either.

Comment: @analina: What is `n.xpath()` returning on the first iteration?